# How do I call a function in vs code using python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'll want to know how to call a function in vs code. I read the answer to similar questions, but they don't work:

```
def userInput(n):
    return n*n
userInput(5)
```

And appends nothing

```
def Input(n):
    return n*n
```

And in the terminal:

```
from file import *
from: can't read /var/mail/file
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the first snippet. You seem to have defined a function and called it. Did you want to print the return value?

Comment: Please don't think I'm being rude, but I think you should look for a basic introduction to the Python programming language.

Comment: Is the problem that you want to see the output? If so you have to print it like @quamrana said.

Comment: python -u "/home/eugenio/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/file.py"

Comment: @Nicholas Hunter that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly in the first picture. In order to call a function in python on vs code you first have to define the function, which you did by typing `def userInput(n):`. If you want to see the result of your function, you should not use return, you should use print instead. Return is a keyword- so when your computer reaches the return keyword it attempts to send that value from one point in your code to another. If you want to see the result of your code, typing print (n) would work better.

Your code should look like this:

```
def userInput(n):
    print (n * n)
userInput(5)
```

The code would print the result 25

Comment: Of course. Here is an article about the difference, it can get confusing sometimes. https://pythonprinciples.com/blog/print-vs-return/

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal is your general way to access your operating system, so you have to tell it that you want it to interpret your Python code first.

If you want to run the file you're typing in, you have to first know the location of that file. When you type `ls` in your terminal, does the name of your Python file show up? If not, hover over the tab in VSCode (it's close to the top of the editor) and see what path appears. Then in your terminal type `cd` (short for "change directory") and then the path that you saw, minus the `<your filename here>.py` bit. Type `ls` again, and you should see your Python file. Now you can type `python <your filename here>.py` to run it (provided you have Python installed).

You could also run the IDLE by just typing `python` in your terminal. This will allow you to write your code line-by-line and immediately evaluate it, but it's easier to write in VSCode and then run it with the method I described before.

Comment: It says: cd -file.py
bash: cd: -f: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]

Comment: And to open IDLE you have to type idle by the way

Comment: @linux `file.py` is your filename here, you want the directory where it's in. maybe your terminal is already at the correct folder, try doing `python file.py` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Really late to the game but if you have the Python extension, see bottom link if you don't have it.  Now you can do a few things in VS to make it easier for reuse:

1. Just go into you code file on the browser of folders in VS Code.
2. Open your file.
3. Highlight in the file itself only what you want to run in this case:

   ```
   def userInput(n):
       return n*n
   ```
4. Press Shift+Enter
5. You will see your code go into an interpreter like below.  Now I can recall function 'userInput(n)' over and over and over and over again how I like.
   [image]

More tips on extension are here too: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-quick-start